# sympy.utilities.iterables.combinations() with replacement?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm experimenting with the sympy api for combinations.

First, *combinations **without** replacement* ...

```py
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import nC
from sympy.utilities.iterables import combinations

nC('abc', 2)
# >>> 3

list(combinations('abc', 2))
# >>> [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c')]
```

I would now like to list the *combinations **with** replacement*

```py
nC('abc', 2, replacement=True)
# >>> 6
```

However, the combinations() method doesn't seem to support a '**replacements**' argument?

```py
Init signature: combinations(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
combinations(iterable, r) --> combinations object

Return successive r-length combinations of elements in the iterable.

combinations(range(4), 3) --> (0,1,2), (0,1,3), (0,2,3), (1,2,3)
Type:           type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a different method

> > Init signature: sympy.utilities.iterables.combinations_with_replacement(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
> >     Docstring:
> >     combinations_with_replacement(iterable, r) --> combinations_with_replacement object
> >
> > Return successive r-length combinations of elements in the iterable
> >     allowing individual elements to have successive repeats.
> >     combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC
> >     Type:           type

Comment: Thanks!  Hmm, there is a permutations() but doesn't seem to be a permutations_with_replacement()

Comment: Added a separate question for permutations - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128621/should-i-use-sympy-utilities-iterables-variations-to-get-permutations-with-rep