# Should I use sympy.utilities.iterables.variations() to get permutations_with_replacement?

Tags: python, sympy

I'm experimenting with sympy's *permutations **without** replacement*

```py
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import nP
from sympy.utilities.iterables import permutations

nP('abc', 2)
# >>> 6

list(permutations('abc', 2))
# >>> [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'a'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]
```

Next, I wan't to try *permutations **with** replacement*.  It seems that there isn't a `permuations_with_replacement()` method similar to the `combinations_with_replacement()` method, but there is a `variations()` method:

```py
from sympy.utilities.iterables import variations

nP('abc', 2, replacement=True)
# >>> 9

list(variations('abc', 2, repetition=True))
# >>>
    [('a', 'a'),
     ('a', 'b'),
     ('a', 'c'),
     ('b', 'a'),
     ('b', 'b'),
     ('b', 'c'),
     ('c', 'a'),
     ('c', 'b'),
     ('c', 'c')]
```

Does the `variations()` method perform the same function as I am expecting with `permutations_with_replacement()` to do?

---

See also: [sympy.utilities.iterables.combinations() with replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54128074/sympy-utilities-iterables-combinations-with-replacement#54128242)

Comment: The `variations` method does exactly what you think it does, which is to calculate the Cartesian product, aptly named `product`, method of the package. `list(sympy.utilities.iterables.product('abc', repeat=2)`. With `repetition=False` `variations` is equal to `permutations` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `variations` method does exactly what you think it does, which is to calculate the Cartesian product, aptly named `product`, method of the package.

This means that `list(sympy.utilities.iterables.product('abc', repeat=2)` will yield the same results.
With `repetition=False`, `variations` is equal to `permutations` instead.

This can also be seen from the internal code of `variations`:

```
if not repetition:
    seq = tuple(seq)
    if len(seq) < n:
        return
    for i in permutations(seq, n):
        yield i
else:
    if n == 0:
        yield ()
    else:
        for i in product(seq, repeat=n):
            yield i
```